# How to get formula based on current filter with EXCEL?

Tags: excel, filter

I have an excel file. I filtered cell according to my conditions.

I could have done this with formulas also by typing IFs.

Rather than typing this formula, is there a way to generate this formula from existing filter?

By this way, I don't have to type a lot of IF statements by hand.

Example

[image]

Let's say I filtered this table with conditions age=3 color=Black body_mark=Star

I could do this just by filtering.

However, I want to create a formula with this and just paste to cell.

By this way, I can use different conditions in different cells.

Apart from that with this formula I want to take TOTAL AGE.

Comment: Can show something that you have done here? Like explaining what you have and what you expect? with a sheet snapshot would be much better..

Comment: Where is your expected answer and where do you want to show it? sorry I am very visual based... Have you used any validate ranges in your columns? Why don't you use a pivot?

Comment: @bonCodigo I just want to print it in any cell. I just want to print TOTAL AGE in a cell that is it. I didn't use any validate ranges. Basically, I have 3 conditions and after filtering this 3 conditions I just want to sum up ages in the form in any cell. I don't know how to use pivot and I don't think that I really need pivot for this kind of simple table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUMIF( range, criteria, [sum_range] )
```

If you use following formula for one criterion:

`SUMIFS("B2:B17",3,"B2:B17")` it will give you total age for all horses with age = 3

In your case use the following `SUMIFS` to to get total age with multiple criteria age = 3, colour = black...etc

```
SUMIFS("B2:B17","B2:B17",3,"C2:C17","Black","D2:D17","Star")
```

Let me explain,
Assume your B2:B17 has age listed for all horses. C2:C17 for colour and D2:D17 for body mark.
So you want to get total age satisfying conditions for all three columns. That's what the `SUMIFS()` does here.

Is that what you are looking for?

Take a look at this article : [SumIfs() web resources](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/04/20/introduction-to-excel-sumifs-formula/) for further understanding.

Comment: But what about other criterias. I have 2 more . color=Black body_mark=Star

Comment: Did you see first 2 values they are same? Did you do it on purpose to sum up only age column.

Comment: I got your point I will try now but I forgot to mention something, I want to sum up ages but I don't want to give it a condition as 3. It can be any number not only 3. I think it will work when I solve this.

Comment: yes it can be any number/colour/body mark. To add two more cents ;) I hope you are using 2007, 2010 Excel. Because in Excel 2003 there's no `SUMIFS`... need to do other workarounds. Good Luck.

Comment: I think I couldn't express myself. I don't want to type any condition to age. But in this formula I have to write in order to sum up the result. I have to write 3 or other number. I don't want only to count cells that have 3. The age can be different. Just to be clear - I just want to filter color and body mark, sum up all ages.

Comment: Then remove the age range (column) and that age condition :) Play around a bit, you will get it well and even find ways to optimize it.